# как в javascript получить результат работы функции переданной как параметр

Tags: javascript

```js
var hh = 0;
funcvoid(param1, param2, function () {
 hh = param1 + param2;
});
alert(hh);
```

В результате в hh хранится 0, что нужно сделать чтоб записать туда param1+param2??

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, вы имеете в виду следующее

```
<script>
    hh = 0;

    ( function( param1, param2, func ) {
        hh = func( param1, param2 );
    } )( 10, 20, function ( param1, param2) {
        return param1 + param2;
    } );

    alert(hh);
</script>
```